# Active Directory The user name or password is incorrect

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem when using Active Directory.

It's weird that my program run fine on my computer but when I copy it to another PC, this error shows up.

I read a lot about AD's issues, but still don't have solution. Please help me to take a look. Thank you

```
string LDAPPath = "LDAP://xxxxxxx/xxxxxx"; // Sorry I can't show it here

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath);

DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

mySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=*))");
mySearcher.PageSize = 5000;

mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

SearchResultCollection mysrs = mySearcher.FindAll();
```

[image: Exception]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error says that there is a problem with the ldap connection.

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. add username and password to `DirectoryEntry`.

```
DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxxxxxx/xxxxxx", username, password);
```

2. check the connection string. you can loook here for more refernce -
   https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I fixed the problem after months. Only add username and password works for me.

Comment: glad to help :) @LeThiLinh